# Filtering data on a known signal

Tags: filters

I have data that is affected by temperature.  How can I filter out the temperature signal considering I have temperature data collected?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer: define a mathematical model of how the temperature affects your data, and use that model to remove the effect of temperature on your data.

Sorry, but with the amount of information you give on your data, the way your temperature affects it or any approach, this is the precisest possible answer.

I'd like to add that what signal processing defines as "filter" is probably not the tool you're looking for, unless you now the spectral properties of your data and your temperature.

Comment: Thanks Marcus.  I was hoping that a "smart filter" tool was out there since I know exactly what is affecting my data...modeling is the next way to go.  Appreciate the time you took to respond.